# Color Tint UIButton Image

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I noticed that when I place a white or black `UIImage` into a `UISegmentedControl` it automatically color masks it to match the tint of the segmented control. I thought this was really cool, and was wondering if I could do this elsewhere as well. For example, I have a bunch of buttons that have a uniform shape but varied colors. Instead of making a PNG for each button, could I somehow use this color masking to use the same image for all of them but then set a tint color or something to change their actual color?

Comment: Can you post the image that you want to use and also image for desired result?

Comment: this do the same from interface builder
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25179217/2051381

Answer (score 708, accepted):

As of iOS 7, there is a new method on `UIImage` to specify the rendering mode. Using the rendering mode `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` will allow the image color to be controlled by the button's tint color.

Objective-C

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Swift

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: I think its better to use button.imageView.tintColor

Comment: @M.Othman only works for me when I use button.tintColor and not button.imageview.tintColor

Comment: Just remember to set image render mode on the image in xcassets per @hashier

Comment: Creating a UIButton of type UIButtonTypeSystem will automatically honor the tintColor you set.

Comment: If your `tintColor` is too dark, make sure `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` is NO. (Or in IB: "Highlighted Adjusts Image" is unchecked.)

Comment: @JasonMoore what an awesome comment! You just made my day, I didn't know why my `UIButton` was changing its `tintColor` and it was that! Thank you

Comment: It is working for setImage for button but not  for background image. And your efforts rewarded in advance

Comment: Just realized my image is actually an emoji... this is not going to work

Answer (score 245):

As Ric already mentioned in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979595/1953914) you can set the render mode in code, you can also do this directly in the image catalog, see attached image below. Just set the `Render As` to `Template Image`

[image]

**Caveat** I have had problems with iOS 7 and this approach. So if you use iOS 7 as well you might want to do it in code as well to be sure, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979595/1953914).

Comment: As a side note, the image file should be black and transparent (not b&w)

Comment: @AxelGuilmin not really. Your image can be any color you want and transparent. Any color different than transparent **will be converted to a generic one** and then it will be tinted with black color by default.

Answer (score 105):

**Custom Buttons** appear in their respective image colors. Setting the button type to "System" in the storyboard (or to **`UIButtonTypeSystem`** in code), will render the button's image with the default tint color.

[image: Button Type System Renders Icons tinted]

(tested on iOS9, Xcode 7.3)

Comment: Which can be avoided with the alwaysTemplate and tintColor methods suggested here. With the advantage of the .system button being you get the change in color with touch down on the tap.

Answer (score 57):

You must set the image rendering mode to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` in order to have the `tintColor` affect the UIImage. Here is the solution in Swift:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image-name")
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**SWIFT 4x**

```
button.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Answer (score 37):

If you have a custom button with a background image.You can set the tint color of your button and override the image with following .

In assets select the button background you want to set tint color.

In the attribute inspector of the image set the value render as to "Template Image"

[image]

Now whenever you set`button.tintColor = UIColor.red` you button will be shown in red.

Comment: if you are here you can go to this link: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/styling-buttons-using-the-asset-catalog/ and go down to template images (to serve as an explanation)

Comment: This is a better solution as it reduces code and pretty much does the same thing as the accepted answer.

Comment: I think this should be the correct one. less code and easy to handle.

Answer (score 18):

In Swift you can do that like so:

```
var exampleImage = UIImage(named: "ExampleImage.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
```

Then in your viewDidLoad

```
exampleButtonOutlet.setImage(exampleImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

And to modify the color

```
exampleButtonOutlet.tintColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1) //your color
```

**EDIT Xcode 8**
Now you can also just the rendering mode of the image in your .xcassets to Template Image and then you don't need to specifically declare it in the `var exampleImage` anymore

Answer (score 14):

Not sure exactly what you want but this category method will mask a UIImage with a specified color so you can have a single image and change its color to whatever you want.

**ImageUtils.h**

```
- (UIImage *) maskWithColor:(UIColor *)color;
```

**ImageUtils.m**

```
-(UIImage *) maskWithColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
    CGImageRef maskImage = self.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = self.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.size.height;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextClipToMask(bitmapContext, bounds, maskImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmapContext, color.CGColor);    
    CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, bounds);

    CGImageRef cImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    UIImage *coloredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cImage];

    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(cImage);

    return coloredImage;    
}
```

Import the ImageUtils category and do something like this...

```
#import "ImageUtils.h"

...

UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:ICON_IMAGE];

UIImage *redIcon = [icon maskWithColor:UIColor.redColor];
UIImage *blueIcon = [icon maskWithColor:UIColor.blueColor];
```

Comment: Use `kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` on `CGBitmapContextCreate`

Comment: Nice, but needs to be tweaked for Retina graphics... When I run this on a Retina image, it returns me a non-retina one.

Comment: To support Retina devices you could use the scale property of the `UIDevice` class: `CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; CGFloat width = self.size.width * scale; CGFloat height = self.size.height * scale;` The `scale` property exists as of iOS 4.0.

Comment: You also need to use the `scale` value when the `UIImage` is created: `UIImage *coloredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cImage scale:scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];`

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4 with customType:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: aRectHere)
    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    button.setImage(buttonImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .white
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**:

This solution could be comfortable if you have already setted your image through xCode interface builder. Basically you have one extension to colorize an image:

```
extension UIImage {
    public func image(withTintColor color: UIColor) -> UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        color.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Then , you can prepare this **UIButton** extension to colorize the image for a particular state:

```
extension UIButton {
    func imageWith(color:UIColor, for: UIControlState) {
        if let imageForState = self.image(for: state) {
            self.image(for: .normal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            let colorizedImage = imageForState.image(withTintColor: color)
            self.setImage(colorizedImage, for: state)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
myButton.imageWith(.red, for: .normal)
```

P.S. (working good also in table cells, you don't need to call `setNeedDisplay()` method, the change of the color is immediate due to the **UIImage** extension..

Answer (score 6):

For Xamarin.iOS (C#):

```
UIButton messagesButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
UIImage icon = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/icon.png");
messagesButton.SetImage(icon.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate), UIControlState.Normal);
messagesButton.TintColor = UIColor.White;
messagesButton.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 25, 25);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're arriving here after iOS 15 and you're using the new `UIButton.Configuration` APIs, then you might need to do it via the `imageColorTransformer`.

Looks like this:

```
configuration.imageColorTransformer = UIConfigurationColorTransformer { _ in .green }
```

For convenience, you can create an extension:

```
extension UIButton.Configuration {
    func imageColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIButton.Configuration {
        var configuration = self
        configuration.imageColorTransformer = UIConfigurationColorTransformer { _ in color }
        return configuration
    }
}

// Usage:
configuration = configuration.imageColor(.green)
```

As with the other answers, the image itself has to be "Render As - Template Image" in the Xcode Assets, or in code `image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`

---

**BONUS TIP**:
What if you want the image color to change when the button is highlighted? Then your configuration extension can look like this:

```
func imageColor(whenNormal: UIColor,
                whenHighlighted: UIColor,
                isHighlighted: Bool) -> UIButton.Configuration {
    var configuration = self
    configuration.imageColorTransformer = UIConfigurationColorTransformer { _ in
        isHighlighted ? whenHighlighted : whenNormal
    }
    return configuration
}
```

And this itself has to be called from a `configurationUpdateHandler` context, like this:

```
someButton.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
    guard var configuration = button.configuration else {  return }
    configuration.image = UIImage(named: "some_image")
    configuration = configuration.imageColor(whenNormal: .green,
                                             whenHighlighted: .green.withAlphaComponent(0.7),
                                             isHighlighted: button.isHighlighted)
    button.configuration = configuration
}
```

Note that the `configurationUpdateHandler` is also where you can actually define a different image based on button state(s).

Comment: thanks a lot !  the correct and only answer now

Comment: This answer should be way up to the top. Specifically the detail about "Render As - Template Image" eluded me.

Answer (score 5):

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

If you are setting `UIButton.tintColor` by `UIColor(r:g:b:alpha:)`, remember to divide values by `255`. Those RGB values should be in between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manually mask your image, here is updated code that works with retina screens

```
- (UIImage *)maskWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGImageRef maskImage = self.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = self.size.width * self.scale;
    CGFloat height = self.size.height * self.scale;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextClipToMask(bitmapContext, bounds, maskImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmapContext, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, bounds);

    CGImageRef cImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    UIImage *coloredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cImage scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];

    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(cImage);

    return coloredImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You Should Try

After Setting The Frame

```
NSArray *arr10 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn1,btn2,nil];
for(UIButton *btn10 in arr10)
{
CAGradientLayer *btnGradient2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
btnGradient2.frame = btn10.bounds;

btnGradient2.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:151.0/255.0f green:206.0/255.5 blue:99.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:126.0/255.0f green:192.0/255.5 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1]CGColor],
                       nil];
[btn10.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient2 atIndex:0];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

```
    let image = UIImage(named:"NoConnection")!

 warningButton = UIButton(type: .system)        
    warningButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    warningButton.tintColor = UIColor.lightText
    warningButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:-100,y:0), size: CGSize(width: 59, height: 56))

    self.addSubview(warningButton)
```

Answer (score 2):

To set white colour of the image(arrow icon) on the button, we're using:

```
let imageOnButton = UIImage(named: "navForwardArrow")?.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.white)
button.setImage(imageOnButton, for: .normal)
```

Known issue: The icon looses its white colour while the button is pressed.

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Change button image or image view tint color Swift :

```
btn.imageView?.image = btn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

btn.imageView?.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change button image or image view tint color Swift :

```
let image = UIImage(named: "map")
mapButton.setImage(image!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
mapButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 0):

None of above worked for me, because tint was cleared after click. I had to use

```
button.setImageTintColor(Palette.darkGray(), for: UIControlState())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with masking image in highlighted state. I didn't want it to happen. If You have the same problem, check this out: *adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false*

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15+

If you have a UIButton based on an SF symbol and you created the button with a configuration, you can update the color after the fact as follows:

```
if var config = myButton.configuration {
      let image = config.image?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [.systemBlue]))
      config.image = image
      myButton.configuration = config
      myButton.setNeedsUpdateConfiguration()
}
```

Alternatively if you're trying to update the color of a button image you pulls from your app's assets catalog, this may do it:

```
if var config = myButton.configuration {
      let image = config.image?.withTintColor(.systemBlue, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
      config.image = image
      myButton.configuration = config
      myButton.setNeedsUpdateConfiguration()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5, using Storyboard:**
Make sure you *don't set the foreground color* of the UIButton in Attributes Inspector(see image).
Otherwise, if you set it, it will ignore all programmatic configurations!

Just let it be `default`.

[image: 1]