# Tint UIButton's image from interface builder with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I have a `UIButton` whose `image` property I'm setting from interface builder. I want this image to be tinted with the superview's `tintColor`. With code, I can set the image's rendering mode to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`, but how do I do this from interface builder?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Got it after a bit of looking around. I had the button type as custom in IB, but switching it to system type now uses the template rendering mode for the `UIButton`'s `image`.

Comment: Like [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

Comment: Thanks a lot for following up - this helped me.