# Changing tintcolor for a specific TabBarItem in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uicolor, uitabbaritem

I have 3 TabBarItems in my ViewController
One of them is default when screen loaded. But it is not highlighted
I am trying to highlight it manually

```
verride func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let items = self.TabBar.items as? [UITabBarItem]? {
            let button = items![1]
            button.image = button.image?.tabBarImageWithCustomTint(UIColor.redColor())
        }
```

I am getting an error that "Value of type UIImage has no member tabBarImageWithCustomTint"
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to set mode for images. Here i am explaining using `ImageAssets`

Step 1: Add image to `ImageAssets`.

Step 2: Set the `Render As` to `Template Image` from attribute inspector

**See screenshot:**

[image]

And keep the same code which you have done already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do:

```
button.image?.tabBarImageWithCustomTint = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: Never mind have a look at Nick Wargnier comment on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829356/color-tint-uibutton-image He explains how to change the tint color of an image on a button.

Comment: decided to change tabBarItem to regular Button