# How to change UIButton's Image color on highlight

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to change the color of an `UIButton`'s image when the user clicks on the `UIButton`through `Interface Builder` without having to create a new image. These are the settings for the `UIButton` both `Normal` and `Highlighted` state:

[image]
[image]

But the image keeps the same color.. What am I missing in order to make it work?

Comment: take 2 image instead .. 1 for selected and 1 for default

Comment: @EICaptain I might end up using 2 images, but I'd like to know if it's possible to achieve what I want just using IB

Comment: the reason u r used the same image for two different states

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik you can change the color of the image using the tint color of the UIButton, but I can't get it working using IB, you can check an example on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829356/color-tint-uibutton-image

Comment: Hey Signo! If you might switch to setting tint color in code, I can provide you a simple solution which I used. 

I prepared custom class that changed `tintColor` depends on the `isHighlighted` state. 

`class MenuButton: UIButton {
    
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted == true {
                tintColor = .brightSkyBlue
            } else {
                tintColor = .paleGrey
            }
            tintColorDidChange()
        }
    }
}`

Comment: A Widera's comment should really be an answer!