# How to set the color of the image view in UIButton on type Custom?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've tried everything and nothing is happening. It just stays black. Am I missing something? I tried using the UIButton's image view but it doesn't make a change.

```
lazy var addFriendButton: UIButton = {
    self.friendButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)


    self.friendButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 80)
    self.friendButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.friendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.friendButton.setTitle("Add Friend", forState: .Normal)
    self.friendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
    self.friendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addFriend), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


    let addButtonImage = UIImage(named: "AddFriend")
    addButtonImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)



    self.friendButton.setImage(addButtonImage, forState: .Normal)
    self.friendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.friendButton.imageView?.image = addButtonImage
    // Not working here
    self.friendButton.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return self.friendButton
}()
```

Comment: What's the file format of the `AddFriend` image?

Comment: it's a png file. When I try system, it works but I need to use Custom for my requirement.

Comment: Try setting the rendering mode in XCAssets, not in code. Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27122597/4475605

Comment: Okay, I've set it and the button is still not white unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean "set the color of an image?" An image is composed of pixels that have a fixed color. You can't change the color of the image you are installing in a button.

Comment: I mean the tint color of the image view of the UIButton, or the icon of the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624153-withrenderingmode):

> - withRenderingMode(_:)
>
> **Creates and returns a new image** object with the specified rendering mode.

So just writing `addButtonImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` doesn't change the `addButtonImage`. The way to use it would be like this:

```
var addButtonImage = UIImage(named: "AddFriend")
addButtonImage = addButtonImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

or you can simply use this one line:

```
let addButtonImage = UIImage(named: "AddFriend")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

Comment: Okay, gotcha! I think that's where I went where wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sam_M's answer updated to Swift 3:

```
let addButtonImage = UIImage(named: "AddFriend")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```