# ios button shows image only when tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I have below code for setting image on my button:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "X", in: getBundleForCommon(), compatibleWith: nil)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
```

But image only appears on button when it is tapped and then goes away.

How can I persistently have image on my button which is not affected when tapped.

Comment: Try this line..Button.setBackgroundImage(pickedImage, for: .normal)

Comment: already tried setBackgroundImage. does not help.

Comment: Look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431695/how-to-set-the-color-of-the-image-view-in-uibutton-on-type-custom

Comment: Are you setting any property of button other than image ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan, yes setting below properties as well: Button.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicButton.frame.size.height / 2
Button.clipsToBounds = true
Button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
Button.layer.borderColor = VxColors.greyDark.color.cgColor -> these all take effect. only the image is seen only when tapping on the button.

Comment: Try commenting them and see if it works and also make sure button is custom type and you are not setting any tittle color or something ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan commented them out, no difference, yes my button is custom and state is default. no color is set.

Comment: I tried using another image and it works fine. so problem is with image. weird part is same image works if i used a imageview but does not work if i use a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this,

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named:"x"), for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named:"x"), for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: there must be some error from your side, delete the button and drag new button from object library

Answer (score 0):

Setting image on UIButton with Swift:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named:"x"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "X", in: getBundleForCommon(), compatibleWith: nil)?
.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
for: UIControlState()
```

instead of

```
for: .normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is being created with `alwaysTemplate` which means the color information will be ignored.

Set the button `tintColor` and the image will display without needing to tap it.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "X", in: getBundleForCommon(), compatibleWith: nil)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.tintColor = .red
```

If the image is display ready, remove the `alwaysTemplate`.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "X", in: getBundleForCommon(), compatibleWith: nil)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```