# IOS/Objective-C: Set imagerenderingmode of image with Storyboard and code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I created a button in storyboard and I now want to change its tint in code.  Changing the tint alone has no effect as I think I need to set the UIImageRenderingMode.  However, my code is not working:

Can anyone suggest syntax to change `uiimagerenderingmode` in code when the button was created in storyboard?

FOLLOWING HAS NO EFFECT:

```
 self.callButton.imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

FOLLOWING THROWS ERROR `property uiimagerenderingmodealwaystemplate not found`:

```
[self.callButton.image.imageWithRenderingMode UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Typo/syntax issue - you want `[self.callButton.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this:

In your storyboard, [make sure to set "Render as" to "Template Image"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122597/981049) (the image itself should be black & white) and then you can call `self.callButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]`.

like this:

[image: Template Image]

p.s. I'm using a PDF file for my image, which is why I have the "Single Scale" selected and "Preserve Vector Data" checkbox set to on; if you're using PNG, that checkbox should be set to off and you should have `@2x` graphics.