# How to change the size AND the color of an SF Symbol ? (UIKit)

Tags: uikit, nsimage, sf-symbols

I'm trying to add an SF Symbol to a Button.
And I've found that I can change it's pointSize, weight and scale OR it's tint.

But I don't know how to implement both kind of customization.

```
self.Button = makeToolBarButton(buttonTitle: "plus", buttonFont: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: buttonSize), image: NSImage(named: "plus.circle.filled")?.withSymbolConfiguration(.init(pointSize: 15, weight: .bold, scale:.large)), { button in 
button.params["actionType"] = ButtonType.image
}
```

Comment: Confusingly, you add `.withTintColor` on the end of a UIImage !

Comment: Be aware though that BUTTONS are now totally different - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74368135/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combines both point size and color in one expression:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle.filled", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 15.0))?.withTintColor(UIColor.red), for: .normal)
```

Another example:

```
let sc = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(
                             pointSize: 17, weight: .light, scale: .medium)

let im = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.left.and.right", withConfiguration: sc)!

btn.setImage(im.withTintColor(.lightGray), for: [])
```